# updating element inside nested array mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am struggling to update element inside nested arrray in mongoDB.

Lets say I have this schema:

```
var question = new Schema({
  problem: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  multipleChoices: [{
    type: String,
    required: true
  }],
  correctAnswer: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  }
});

var testCategorySchema = new Schema({
  category: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  tests: [{
    version: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    questions: [question]
  }]
});
```

For example I have instance of that schema like this:

```
{
  category: "Math",
  tests: [
    {
      version: "1A",
      questions: [
         {
           problem: "blablabla",
           multiplechoices: [
            "bla bla", "blb blb", "blc blc"
          ],
           correctAnswer: 1
         },
         {
           problem: "blibliblibli",
           multiplechoices: [
            "bla bla", "blb blb", "blc blc"
          ]
           correctAnswer: 1
         }
      ]
    },
    {
      version: "1B",
      questions: [
         {
           problem: "auauauauau",
           multiplechoices: [
            "bla bla", "blb blb", "blc blc"
          ]
           correctAnswer: 1
         },
         {
           problem: "blibliblibli",
           multiplechoices: [
            "bla bla", "blb blb", "blc blc"
          ]
           correctAnswer: 1
         }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I add new question to the math category when test version is : 1A using mongooseJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`update`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.update/) and [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) with the positional operator [`$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/positional/):

```
db.test.update(
    {
        category: 'Math',
        'tests.version': '1A'
    }, 
    {
        $push: {
            'tests.$.questions': { 
                problem: 'test',
                multiplechoices: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                correctAnswer: 1
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it.
But how can I achieve it with mongoose? I try to do this `TestCategory
    .findOne({category: req.params.TestCategory, tests: {$elemMatch: { version: req.params.version } } })`, is that already correct?

Comment: just use the `update` instead of `findOne` and fill the values accordingly... there is no need for `$elemMatch` here, that's what the `$` is for.

Comment: okay, but how can I display like "Test category not found", if I only use the update?

sorry, still little bit confuse hehe

Comment: check what returns from this update function. If I'm not mistaken you should get how many documents were updated. so if nothing was found you should get a 0. you can also use `findOneAndUpdate` instead of regular `update` and there you will get a `null` if nothing was found.

Comment: Ohh great, i got it now.
But can you show me how to do it using findOneAndUpdate() ?

Comment: it's very similar to `update`. you can read about it in the mongoose docs: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
  Test.findOne( {category:"Math", tests.version:"1A"}, function(err, result){
   if (!err && result) {
    result.tests.questions.push({"new question"}); //push ur new question 
    var test = new Test(result);  //this is ur mongoose mdel
    test.save(function(err, result2){    //update
        if(!err) {
           console.log(result2); //updated result
        } console.log(err);
    })  

   } else console.log(err);
});
```